# Match same string as composed word for first 3 positions of the row

Tags: regex

I use this regex to remove similar lines

**Search pattern:** `^(.{5,})(.*)$\R\1.*`
**Replace pattern:** `$1$2`

For example for line like this

```
alfax jack
alfax meta
```

regex give me this output line

```
alfax jack
```

I need a regex to print another thing. I try to explain, I have

```
alfax gamma one
alfax gamma second
```

and I need to have this output

```
alfax gamma
```

In other words I consider 'same string' as a composed words and not only similar line. Same compund word should be within the first 3 positions of the row.

Is there a regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand your needs, this does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^((?:\w+\h+){2,3})(.*)$\R\1.*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (           # group 1
    (?:         # non capture group
      \w+         # 1 or more word character
      \h+         # 1 or more horizontal space
    ){2,3}      # end group, must appear 2 or 3 times
  )           # end group 1
  (.*)        # group 2, 0 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
\R          # any kind of linebreak
\1          # backreference to group 1
.*          # 0 or more any character but newline
```

**Replacement:**

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: it's almost perfect, but instead of getting *alfax gamma one*, *alfax beta gamma blah1* I need to get `alfax gamma`, `alfax beta gamma`.

Comment: @AlexDoc: Use only `$1` in replacement, see my edit.

Comment: @AlexDoc: And, please, don't [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66906758/372239)

Comment: thank you, now it works! I delete cross post